# Way to differentiate table and other text in xsl-fo

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am setting a column-count to 2 in my simple-page-master.

I am using xsl-fo to generate the pdf, the text now splits into two columns perfectly.

However, I am now with a new issue caused by this, it also splits the tables into two columns, which I don't want to, I want to leave the table as it is and only split the text.

Here is the complete fo file:
http://pastebin.com/Z7Nkm279

The column count is set to "2" in layout-master-set.

Could any experts offer some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: **Please** provide a COMPLETE FO document (NOT just a skeleton) that demonstrates the problem. You can paste it at http://pastebin.com or a similar service.

Comment: Yeah, I have uploaded it to pastebin.com, let me know if that works.

Comment: this is the version in which I already took out the @span="all". I did put it there before, but no effect, thus I took it out.

Comment: When running your FO file through XEP, there are several warnings like this one: **[warning] 'span' attribute on block ignored because the element is not a direct child of a flow**. You have to fix those if you want the spanning of tables to work. I did mention this requirement in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let your XSLT stylesheet wrap tables in `<fo:block>` elements that have `span="all"` set:

```
<fo:block span="all">
  <fo:table width="100%" ...>
  ...
  </fo:table>
<fo:block>
```

This will make the table span all the columns of a multi-column region (provided that the `<fo:block>` is a direct child of `<fo:flow>`). Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xsl-20011015/slice7.html#span.

Comment: @mzin, this is not working. The table is still splits into two columns.

Comment: yes, please see the updated question with the fo. I have taken out the @span attribute. Let me know if more info is needed. Thx